# Inertia/Gravity in Distance Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, determinants, differential-equations

The Cayley-Menger Determinant, D(N), slickly calculates the N-dimensional simplex
volume of any N+1 points.  One constraint in our 3D world is that D(4)=0.

Give each point a mass (Mi) and dynamic interdistances (i.e., Rij(t) are functions of
"time") according to inertia and non-relativistic "Newtonian gravity".  Is there a simple
mathematical way to express the resulting dynamic constraints in these terms?

I'm basically wondering if these interdistances are somehow superior to normal
coordinates in multi-body problems, but gravity doesn't appear to fit nicely...sorry
for the vague question!

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html

Comment: I really can't parse this question.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask whether it is better to do classical dynamical systems of $N$ interacting particles instead of on $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$, where the position and momentum of each of the particles are specified, but on something like $\mathbb{R}^{N(N-1)}$, where the relative distances and relative speeds of pairs of particles are specified. If that is the case, the answer is probably "no" for sufficiently large number of particles: $N(N-1)$ is bigger than $6N if $N > 7$, so you have too many degrees of freedom and requires certain constraints (triangle inequality and what not). 

Comment: Willie's right about my goal: I'm looking for the formula for an interdistance acceleration, $d^{2}R_{12}/dt^{2}=f( \lbrace M_{i},R_{ij},dR_{ij}/dt \rbrace )$, for some number of point masses, like eight. In principle, my only solution is to first numerically embed these eight points into space and then to calculate this interdistance acceleration, but I was hoping for an analytic method (which could avoid numerics altogether since I don't need the embedding in the end).  Can this really only be done numerically?  I would even be willing to relax some of the geometry constraints if it helped!